# Comparing 2 columns and add blanks in 2nd column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 columns where some cells have the same value.
I would like to sort both columns and  put blank cells to another column if it doesn't have duplication.

Example:
| Test1 | Test1 |
| Test2 | Test3 |
| Test3 | *blank* |

I would like to do like this:
| Test1 | Test1 |
| Test2 | *blank* |
| Test3 | Test3 |

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do exactly the same without macros, but here is a workaround which is pretty close:

1. sort your data on first column (if it's not already sorted)
2. create a new column with the formula `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"",A2)`
3. delete or hide your original second column

   - (to delete it, at first you need to convert calculated column to constants: select the column, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then go to home - paste - values only)

[image]